# Sonarqube issue - Change this "try" to a try-with-resources. How to handle conditional resources?

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-with-resources

Checked similar questions regarding this topic but I did not find solution to my use-case.

Following method shows Sonar issue with `Major code smell` as - `Change this "try" to a try-with-resources.`

```
private void readExcel() {
        Workbook workbook = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        
        try {
            File file = path.toFile();
            if (file.getName().endsWith(FILE_TYPES.XLS.value) && (file.length() / (1024 * 1024)) < 25) {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(file));
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                readExcel(sheet);
            } else if ((file.getName().endsWith(FILE_TYPES.XLSX.value)) && (file.length() / (1024 * 1024)) < 25) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                readExcel(sheet);
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(FILE_TYPES.CSV.value)) {
                // Apache POI cant read/write CSV. Hence using Java IO.
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                readExcel(br);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException ex) {
                // set invalid flags and call clean-up
        } finally {
            try {
                if (workbook != null) {
                    workbook.close();
                }
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // set invalid flags and call clean-up
            }
        } // try-catch-finally closed
    }
```

Is this false positive sonar issue?

Comment: At least BufferedReader can be try-with-resources block so do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) is an `AutoCloseable`.
[`XSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html) is an `AutoCloseable`.
[`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is an `AutoCloseable`.

They all need their own *try-with-resources*.

Get rid of `Workbook workbook = null;` and `BufferedReader br = null;`, and the code in the `finally` block, because that's all old-style pre-try-with-resources.

```java
private void readExcel() {
    try {
        File file = path.toFile();
        if (file.getName().endsWith(FILE_TYPES.XLS.value) && (file.length() / (1024 * 1024)) < 25) {
            try (Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(file))) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                readExcel(sheet);
            }
        } else if ((file.getName().endsWith(FILE_TYPES.XLSX.value)) && (file.length() / (1024 * 1024)) < 25) {
            try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                readExcel(sheet);
            }
        } else if (file.getName().endsWith(FILE_TYPES.CSV.value)) {
            // Apache POI cant read/write CSV. Hence using Java IO.
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                readExcel(br);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException ex) {
        // set invalid flags and call clean-up
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering that the first two operations use the common base type `Workbook` and are otherwise identical too, I wouldn’t say that they *need* their own try-with-resources.

Comment: @Holger Well, they do need their own constructor calls, and since the constructor call is *usually* in the `try` bracket, they get their own blocks. But you're right, they could be combined, but it's hardly necessary for this simple code.

Comment: Of course, people have different opinion about which amount of code duplication is acceptable. Since sharing the code would slightly raise the complexity, five lines of code are a borderline case. To me, even having `file.getName()` repeated three times feels wrong…